# Using Google oauth in a deployment

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth

I've set up an ASP.Net Core project to use Google OAuth signin from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

I created a client ID & secret using the settings 'Web server' with address 'https://localhost:5001/signin-google' and exposed the secrets to the app as described in the tutorial. I have a basic view which is just the minimum required HTML & JS to show a 'Sign in with Google' button and allow authentication (verified working on localhost).

I created a deployment in a docker container on a Raspberry Pi on the local network. When I navigate to the view with the Google sign in button and click it, I get an error of

```
Error: invalid_request

Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.
```

In the error details it specifies the redirect URL as:

```
redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/x.x.x.x:8000?id=auth572720
```

where  x.x.x.x is the address of the Pi on our local network

I am assuming this is because the client expects a redirect URL of 'https://localhost..etc' but is getting 'http://x.x.x.x'.

I am unsure how to solve this, it seems like I may need to create another token to enable authentication on my Raspberry Pi (e.g. create another 'web server' OAuth sign in using the re-direct address 'http://x.x.x.x.etc/signin-google' but when I try this I get an error of 'Must be a top private domain'.

All in all this is very frustrating, and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a new credential, just add the new redirect URL to the existing credential.

The redirect URL domain must be a TLD. Choose something like `localhost.mydomain.com` and then add an entry in your /etc/hosts file to resolve `localhost.mydomain.com` to `x.x.x.x`

Comment: If I'm running it in a docker container on a raspberry pi, I'd change the hosts in the container not the pi, right?

Comment: the redirect URL is passed to the browser as a redirect. So you need to change it wherever your browser is resolving it's domain names. If you own the domain and have the ability to change your own DNS records, the best way is to add an A record so it resolves for all devices. Also remember that you can configure any number of declared redirect URLS, so `localhost1`, `localhost2`, etc etc to deal with your various test configuration variations.